# Hierarquia de páginas Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, breadcrumbs

Estou a criar um site que terá duas paginas de contactos (uma para cada morada).
Queria criar uma estrutura de breadcrumbs do tipo:

- `Home > Contactos > Loja 1`
- `Home > Contactos > Loja 2`

cujos os links seriam `contactos/loja-1` e `contactos/loja-2`.

Como faço isso?

Answer (score 0):

Como estás a utilizar [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress), a solução mais fácil de se optar por fazer isso seria utilizar um plugin de `breadcrumbs` como por exemplo:

- [Breadcrumb](https://wordpress.org/plugins/breadcrumb/screenshots/)
- [Breadcrumb NavXT](https://wordpress.org/plugins/breadcrumb-navxt/screenshots/)

Podes pesquisar por mais plugins ao teu gosto dentro deste tópico (breadcrumbs) em: [Wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=Breadcrumb)

Ou podes também optar por construir os teus próprios `breadcrumbs` sem plugins como é explicado aqui nesta página: [Creating breadcrumbs without a plugin](http://thewebtaylor.com/articles/wordpress-creating-breadcrumbs-without-a-plugin)

Comment: obrigado. esses plugins não resolvem o problema, visto que nenhum permite definir a estrutura de breadcumbs por página.

Comment: @MiguelBorges eu não tenho o Wordpress aqui instalado, mas tenho quase certeza de que estes também são incluídos para páginas. Se não estão já incluídos deve haver uma opção qualquer para isso, pois eu já usei o plugin [**Breadcrumbs**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/breadcrumb/) há cerca de 1 ano para cá e lembro-me de que eles apareciam em páginas e até o próprio plugin refere isso na sua descrição. Isso também poderá ser um problema a haver com o tema, mas para isso sempre tens a solução de implementá-los utilizando **short-codes** como também é referido nessa mesma descrição do plugin.